# Windows app that aids in making "ORDERED LISTS"?

Tags: windows, data

Dose anyone know a cool app for windows that will aid me in making large ordered lists. I'm involved in a online community and one of the things we do is make a lot of lists "top 20 X" and "top 100 x" type things.

What I am looking for is a simple app that I can enter the list items in as I think of them and then simply drag them up and down the list to order them as I like.

I know I can copy/paste in a text editor, but with large lists this can be cumbersome. I am hoping a simple "drag it up, drag it down" kind of thing might be around somewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to export your data afterward, or are you OK with your data being captive in the app?

Comment: Maybe you could (ab)use a ToDo list maker? I woudl expect those to have drag capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a cool web-app that dose exactly what I am asking, is free and doesn't even require registration... I hope it helps anyone else looking at this question. - http://listmoz.com